# Унаследовать класс "треугольник" от класса "точка"

Tags: c#, наследование

Как нужно подправить следующий код, чтобы класс треугольник был унаследован от класса точка? То есть после изменений в конструктор класса треугольник будут передаваться не три объекта типа точка, а шесть координат точек треугольника.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
class Point
{
    public float x, y;
    public Point(float _x, float _y)
    {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }
}
class Triangle
{
    public Point a { set; get; }
    public Point b { set; get; }
    public Point c { set; get; }

    public Triangle(Point _a, Point _b, Point _c)   //конструктор
    {
        a = _a;
        b = _b;
        c = _c;
    }
    public void sd_right(float d)   //сдвиг вправо
    {
        a.x = +d; b.x = +d; c.x = +d;
    }
    public void sd_left(float d)    //сдвиг влево
    {
        a.x = -d; b.x = -d; c.x = -d;
    }
    public void sd_up(float d)  //сдвиг верх
    {
        a.y = +d; b.y = +d; c.y = +d;
    }
    public void sd_down(float d)    //сдвиг вниз
    {
        a.y = -d; b.y = -d; c.y = -d;
    }
    public float R(Point _a, Point _b)
    {
        return Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(_a.x - _b.x, 2) + Math.Pow(_a.y - _b.y, 2)));
    }
    public void sd_alfa(float d)    //поворот на угол d
    {
        Point M = new Point((a.x + b.x + c.x) / 3, (a.y + b.y + c.y) / 3);
        a.x = M.x + Convert.ToSingle(R(M, a) * Math.Cos(d));
        a.y = M.y - Convert.ToSingle(R(M, a) * Math.Sin(d));
        b.x = M.x + Convert.ToSingle(R(M, b) * Math.Cos(d));
        b.y = M.y - Convert.ToSingle(R(M, b) * Math.Sin(d));
        c.x = M.x + Convert.ToSingle(R(M, c) * Math.Cos(d));
        c.y = M.y - Convert.ToSingle(R(M, c) * Math.Sin(d));
    }
    public void sd_rad(float r) //увелечение на r
    {
        float d = 0;
        Point M = new Point((a.x + b.x + c.x) / 3, (a.y + b.y + c.y) / 3);
        a.x = Convert.ToSingle((R(M, a) + r) * Math.Cos(d));
        a.y = -Convert.ToSingle((R(M, a) + r) * Math.Sin(d));
        b.x = Convert.ToSingle((R(M, b) + r) * Math.Cos(d));
        b.y = -Convert.ToSingle((R(M, b) + r) * Math.Sin(d));
        c.x = Convert.ToSingle((R(M, c) + r) * Math.Cos(d));
        c.y = -Convert.ToSingle((R(M, c) + r) * Math.Sin(d));
    }

    public void show()  //вывод координат
    {
        Console.WriteLine("a(x,y)={0},{1}\nb(x,y)={2},{3}\nc(x,y)={4},{5}", a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y, c.x, c.y);

    }
};

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Point a = new Point(1, 1);
        Point b = new Point(3, 3);
        Point c = new Point(3, 1);
        Triangle T = new Triangle(a, b, c);
        T.show();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

треугольник - это три точки. Одну мы наследуем, две других создаем в классе. Как это реализовать, правив код выше?

Comment: Он **не** должен быть унаследован от класса точка. Точка - это точка, треугольник - это три линии, чье положение в кпространстве можно описать тремя координатами. Это **разные** вещи.

Comment: Не наследуйте треугольник от точки, он таковой не является. И нет никаких весомых аргументов передавать в конструктор шесть координат, вместо трех объектов.

Comment: Кстати, есть ли какая-то веская причина использовать `float`, а не `double`? (Подсказка: скорее всего, нету.)

Comment: Всем спасибо, я понимаю, что программа самодостаточна и логична, но преподаватель решил "добавить перца" - сделай так, чтобы класс Треугольник был унаследован от класса точка и всё тут :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Обновление:**

Мне кажется, вы должны аргументировано *возразить* преподавателю.

Дело в том, что наследование не есть средство повторного использования кода, тем более не средство для того, чтобы представить *одну* вершину, а две другие добавить как свойство. Наследование есть способ выразить, что объект-наследник есть частным случаем объекта-предка. Основание — [принцип подстановки Лисков](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2).

В вашем случае треугольник **не является** частным случаем точки. В частности, он **не может** быть разумным способом использован, например, вместо точки, представляющей *вершину* треугольника. Вершины треугольника есть три точки, но не три треугольника.

В противоположность этому, для *настоящего*, правильного наследования такая замена всегда имеет смысл. Например, поскольку селёдка *является* рыбой, то если вас отправят за рыбой, а вы принесёте селёдку, вы сделаете всё правильно.

Разумеется, можно чисто формально унаследовать любой объект от любого. Но *возможность*, предоставляемая языком, не означает, что вы имеет право ей пользоваться с точки зрения объектно-ориентированного дизайна.

Если преподаватель будет настаивать, подумайте об альтернативных источниках знаний.

---

Вы не должны хотеть такого. Треугольник *не является* точкой ни в каком разумном смысле.

То, как сделано сейчас — правильно.

---

Если есть некая общая функциональность, правильнее вынести ещё в общий *интерфейс*. Возможно, ещё можно сделать общий класс-предок `GeometricObject`.

---

Мне сложно понять, что есть «переопределение» в терминах задания. С моей точки зрения, код должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
public interface IMovable
{
    void Move(double dx, double dy);
    Point Center { get; }
    void RotateAbout(Point p, double alpha)
}

public static class MovableExtensions
{
    public static void MoveRight(this IMovable self, double d) //сдвиг вправо
    {
        self.Move(+d, 0);
    }

    public static void MoveLeft(this IMovable self, double d) //сдвиг влево
    {
        self.Move(-d, 0);
    }

    public static void MoveUp(this IMovable self, double d) //сдвиг вверх
    {
        self.Move(0, +d);
    }

    public static void MoveDown(this IMovable self, double d) //сдвиг вниз
    {
        self.Move(0, -d);
    }

    public static void RotateAboutCenter(this IMovable self, double alpha)
    {
        self.RotateAbout(self.Center, alpha);
    }
}

public class Point : IMovable
{
    public double X { get; private set; }
    public double Y { get; private set; }
    public Point(double _x, double _y)
    {
        X = _x;
        Y = _y;
    }

    public void Move(double dx, double dy)
    {
        X += dx;
        Y += dy;
    }

    public Point Center { get { return this.Clone(); } }

    public void RotateAbout(Point p, double alpha)
    {
        double distanceToRotationCenter = GeoTools.Distance(this, p);
        double dx = distanceToRotationCenter * Math.Cos(d);
        double dy = -distanceToRotationCenter * Math.Sin(d);
        X += dx;
        y += dy;
    }

    internal Point Clone() { return new Point(X, Y); }
}

public static class GeoTools
{
    public static double Distance(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        double dx = p2.X - p1.X;
        double dy = p2.Y - p1.Y;
        return Math.Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }
}

public class Triangle : IMovable
{
    private Point a, b, c;

    public Point A { get { return a.Clone(); } }
    public Point B { get { return b.Clone(); } }
    public Point C { get { return c.Clone(); } }

    public Triangle(Point _a, Point _b, Point _c)
    {
        a = _a.Clone();
        b = _b.Clone();
        c = _c.Clone();
    }

    public void Move(double dx, double dy)
    {
        a.Move(dx, dy);
        b.Move(dx, dy);
        c.Move(dx, dy);
    }

    public Point Center
    {
        get
        {
            return new Point((a.X + b.X + c.X) / 3.0, (a.Y + b.Y + c.Y) / 3.0);
        }
    }

    public void RotateAbout(Point p, double alpha)
    {
        a.RotateAbout(p, alpha);
        b.RotateAbout(p, alpha);
        c.RotateAbout(p, alpha);
    }
}
```

Comment: Почти согласен, но не совсем. См. мой ответ.

Comment: Спасибо @VladD, я допускаю, что не совсем верно понял задание, но преподаватель дал понять, что нужно унаследовать класс треугольник от класса точка. "А как быть с двумя другими точками?" - на этот вопрос препод ответил, что нужно воспользоваться "переопределением". Вот как-то так :(

Comment: @jumpjet67: Обновил ответ.

Comment: "Наследование есть способ выразить, что объект-наследник есть частным случаем объекта-предка." Квадрат является частным случаем прямоугольника, но наследование квадрата от прямоугольника неверно. Обратное наследование возможно в зависимости от требований.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Знаю, читал, википедия -> circle/ellipse problem. Read-only-квадрат является частным случаем, мутабельный нет.

Comment: @VladD, думаю, упомянутая вами проблема круга и эллипса высосана из пальца. В постусловиях метода `Ellipse::stretchX()` нет требования на неизменность длины оси `y` по возвращении из него. Так что ничто не мешает `Circle::stretchX()`-у восстанавливать равенство осей неявным вызовом `stretchY()` внутри себя.

Comment: @Arhad: Ну, хм. Мне кажется, что с точки зрения здравого смысла есть. Мне кажется, любой разработчик ожидает, что код `ell.stretchX(10); ell.stretchY(15);` будет гарантировать, что X == 10 и Y == 15. (Формально, такое поведение, как вы описываете, также противоречит LSP.)

Comment: @VladD 1) именно поэтому так важно описывать постусловия. А то получается, что раз у `Ellipse::stretchX()` нет постусловия *Ellipse::stretchX: (Sₙ, x) → Sₙ₊₁ ⟹ Sₙ.y == Sₙ₊₁.y* (неизменность игрека после `stretchX()`), то круг не ослабляет его (ибо ослаблять нечего) и, следовательно, не нарушает принцип подстановки (с точки зрения контрактного программирования). 2) `разработчик  ожидает` — кто сказал, что класс не может согласовывать данные внутри себя?

Comment: @VladD, и ещё по `разработчик ожидает`: ожидать подобное можно, будь класс эллипса недоступным для расширения. А раз он для расширения доступен, не стоит полагаться на недокументированные ожидания.

Comment: @Arhad: У Ellipse::stretchX очевидное постусловие: поменялось X, больше ничего не поменялось. У Circle другое наблюдаемое поведение: смена X у Ellipse не меняет Y, а у Circle меняет. Так что вы не можете вместо Ellipse везде использовать Circle. Соответственно LSP нарушен.

Comment: @Arhad: Эээ, «не стоит полагаться на недокументированные ожидания». Нигде не документировано, что `new object()` не вызывает какой-нибудь побочный эффект вроде уменьшения переменной `int X` на 1. Это само собой разумеется. Давайте всё же выберемся из формального болота, и обратимся к здравому смыслу. В документации описано наблюдаемое поведение, и если что-то не описано, этого и не должно случаться. Писать после каждого описания метода «и больше никаких видимых изменений не происходит» ну слишком скучно.

Answer (score 2):

Если выбросить из вопроса некорректную часть про наследование, то проблему можно решить добавлением еще одного конструктора, который вызовет первый:

```
public Triangle(Point _a, Point _b, Point _c)   //конструктор
{
    a = _a;
    b = _b;
    c = _c;
}

public Triangle(float ax, float ay, float bx, float by, float cx, float cy)
    : this(new Point(ax, ay), new Point(bx, by), new Point(cx, cy))
{
}

//..........

Triangle T = new Triangle(a, b, c);
T.show();

// теперь можно создавать треугольники и так:
Triangle T2 = new Triangle(1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1);
T2.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Точка может быть базовой для всех фигур только в одном смысле - как координаты фигуры или точка отсчёта. Это может быть удобно для случая, когда мы можем перемещать произвольные фигуры по полю. Т. о. Точка содержит координаты на поле, а все остальные координаты фигуры рассматриваются как относительные и при отрисовке суммируются с базовыми. Так же, можно будет реализовать сращение относительно базовой точки.

Другой осмысленной причины или даже интерпретации наследования от точки я не вижу.

Comment: "Точка может быть базовой для всех фигур только в одном смысле - как координаты фигуры или точка отсчёта"... может этого и хочет автор вопроса )))

Comment: Общее _умение_ есть общий интерфейс (`IMoveable`), но не наследование друг от друга. Наследование есть отношение _is-a_: в любом месте, где используется предок, может быть использован и потомок. Теперь представьте себе, что у вас есть вершина квадрата — точка. Можете ли вы вместо неё использовать треугольник?

Comment: @VladD, в моём варианте базовая точка является просто точкой. Она не вершина треугольника, а точка отсчёта и центр вращения. Помимо неё треугольник состоит из _трёх_ других точек (координаты которых заданы относительно неё). Да, возможно ей можно дать другое имя, например, фигура. Но по сути, это то же самое, что точка.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Проблема в том, что треугольник не _является_ ей. Центр скорее свойство треугольника, чем _сам_ треугольник.

Comment: @VladD, всё зависит от использования. Нельзя говорить о принципе подстановки вне контекста. Если речь идёт о векторном редакторе, например, то я вполне могу захотеть, чтобы любая точка (в том числе вершина фигуры) могда сама отображаться как некоторая фигура. В тамком случае использование точки как базового класса для всех фигур корректно.